# Bash script switch user on the same scritp

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I created bash script on Linux Redhat with vim
My script  is working well on an user.
I need to esxute on the same script this command
su - root  with password
VGDISPLAY -v |grep "LV Status"
the probem is when I execute my script the part of the normal user is done
and the other part with root not done
my question how can I do to execute this
I need to switch in the same script to root

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend **not** switching to the root user in the script for specific tasks/commands but assigning SUDO privileges to your user (by which you are running the script), and using `sudo` command in the script for the tasks/commands that need elevations.

*Hint: By `sudo` command you may run a process on behalf of another user (root probably).*

If you are not familiar with `sudo` command or how to assign SUDO privileges to a user, please see the following link or google it.

- https://phoenixnap.com/kb/linux-sudo-command

PS. Providing SUDO privileges to a user is configurable whether to be used for all commands or limited commands. For testing purposes, you may configure the user to be able to run all commands with `sudo` to gain the privileges, but for production use it is strongly recommended to limit the user to be able to use only necessary commands with `sudo` and nothing more.